# WooCommerce $product->get_price_html method or function location?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have read all questions regarding this, and none of them are to any help. I need the location to the $product->get_price_html method or function.

The reason I need this, is that for some odd reason it started printing all the prices like this:

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    an class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"&gt;DKK&nbsp;1,199.00
</span>
```

[image]

It prints the price just fine, but at every price it prints an unfinished span along with the price like shown above. I suspect that someone has been messing with the $product->get_price_html method or function since I cannot find any other source to the unfinished span.

I'm working on another solution where I just use the following code

```
    <p class="price">
        <span class="customClass">DKK<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?></span>
    </p>
```

[image]

this does print the right price and I've just styled it alike to the original with the customClass, however, this does not print the old price on products that are on sale.

So if anyone has the php code for printing the old price it would be great.

I would also love to have the path to the function or method file for $product->get_price(); as I would like to see if that's what causing the problem.

Comment: [docs](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productget_price_html/) seriously though, did you even look at the docs?

Answer (score 0):

The source of that particular code is in this file:

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-formatting-functions.php
```

It's written in the line number 426 around!!

Let me know if that helps!